# Moment js is not converting as expected to utc time format "11/08/2023 11:03:00" to "2023-08-11 16:33:07"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment js is not converting as expected to utc time format "11/08/2023 11:03:00" to "2023-08-11 16:33:07" tired with

```js
let ScheduledStartDate = "11/08/2023 11:03:00";
let convertedDate = moment(ScheduledStartDate, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
  .utc()
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A");
console.log(convertedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-42PE0rd+wZ2hNXftlM78BSehIGzezNeQuzihiBCvUEB3CVxHvsShF86wBWwQORNxNINlBPuq7rG4WWhNiTVHFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: `console.log(moment.utc(ScheduledStartDate,"MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A"));`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: formatting, from `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss` to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A`

Comment: @eekinci There's no question in the question. Without clarification from the poster, you're guessing what the problem is.

Comment: For me the question is clear from the post.

Comment: @eekinci I'm not sure whether you're a native English speaker but as a native English speaker myself, the question is far from clear.

Comment: But yes, I also think that the question should be clearly mentioned in a post!

Comment: What is your system timezone? What result do you get instead of the expected one?

Comment: For +05:30 I would would expect IST or Sri Lanka

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that the extra 7 seconds in "2023-08-11 16:33:07" is a typo!

Answer (score 1):

move your arguments from `moment` to `utc`:

```js
//const moment = require('moment');

const ScheduledStartDate = "11/08/2023 11:03:00";

const convertedDate = moment.utc(
  ScheduledStartDate,
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
)
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A');

console.log(convertedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```